# Knockout - change an object's 'subclass' by setting a property on it

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, subclass

In Knockout, I have an array of `Setting` entities which may be of different *types* (i.e. 'subclasses' of the Setting entity). These types are dynamic, they may be changed by the user in the UI. Depending on what type the Setting entity is, it requires different object properties, and makes others redundant.

What I'm currently doing (which I want to change), is defining one Setting constructor which has all required properties for all setting types; making the constructor quite huge, and containing a lot of unnecessary properties. When the app data is saved I 'ignore' the properties which shouldn't be on Setting instances according to their types.

I've given it a try in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zmx3u4an/), using a subscription on the `type` property to add/ remove properties on type change. I'd like to know if it is possible in KnockoutJS to **reliably change the properties on an object during run-time** (i.e. will the subscription always fire before the template is updated? ) and will this have **any [positive] impact on performance?**. Or is this approach totally wrong and should I replace the entire object with a subclass instance (if so, won't the subscriptions go lost)?

**EDIT:** The dependant properties are actual data (so they should be saved to their models, not only available in the view). I've tried the component approach but how do I retrieve their properties later? http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zmx3u4an/1/

Comment: Consider using components. You could have each settings subclass own a component name and component params that your "settings editor" could hook up with a component binding. Any common behavior would go in a base class.

Comment: What problems is your initial approach causing?

Comment: @RoyJ code readability + overhead in the data save function (need to remove all properties for each setting according to its type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address saving the properties, I reworked the component code. Some members (mostly computeds) are only for the view, and should not be saved, so I put the save-able stuff in a "data" member:

```
function Setting(params) {
    var self = this;
    // What getData fetches
    self.data = {
        type: ko.observable(params.type),
        value: ko.observable(params.value || '')
    };
    self.data.type.subscribe(function (value) {
        // Give the conversion a little time
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("GetData:", self.getData());
        }, 30);
    });
}
```

Each specialized type is going to add its special members to the base object, and will add a method, `toSetting`, to revert it back to the base object type. The base type has a do-nothing version of `toSetting` in its prototype, so it is always safe to call `toSetting` first thing in the type converter.

I added a `headingSize` parameter to the Title type, and made it determine what heading size the text displays in.

```
function toTitle(setting) {
    var self = setting;
    var data = setting.data;
    var value = data.value();
    self.toSetting();
    data.headingSize = ko.observable(4);
    self.capitalized = ko.computed(function () {
        return value ? value.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1) : '';
    });
    self.headerText = ko.computed(function () {
        return '<h' + data.headingSize() + '>' + self.capitalized() + '</h' + data.headingSize() + '>';
    });
    self.toSetting = function () {
        delete self.data.headingSize;
        delete self.capitalized;
        delete self.toSetting;
    };
    return self;
}
```

I registered it like this:

```
ko.components.register('title', {
    viewModel: toTitle,
    template: '<select data-bind="options:$root.sizes, value: data.headingSize"></select><div data-bind="html:headerText"></div>'
});
```

And I added a button to "save" the settings, which displays what will be saved at the bottom of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/1kfvesq3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use components that are bound in your settings editor but owned by each individual subclass instance.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: settings">
    <select data-bind="options: $root.types, value: type"></select>
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: value"/>
    <div data-bind="component: { name: componentName, params: componentParams }"></div>
</div>
```

Example component name/params for the color setting. These properties would be different for different settings subclasses.

```
this.componentName = 'color-viewer';
this.componentParams = {
    colorText: this.value,
};
```

With this approach, changing the current setting "type" would require you to replace one settings subclass instance with another. This might be a hassle in a trivial case but there's advantages to keeping your models small with a single responsibility.

Comment: I would like to use components & agree with your argument, but I'm still wondering how component VM properties can be retrieved. I understand components are a great way to augment data models with state-related or view-bound properties, & perhaps this wasn't clear from my simple test case, but suppose the getData function needs to retrieve these component-specific properties: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zmx3u4an/1/ How??

Comment: Implement a "getData" method in each subclass that returns an object containing the properties to be saved.

Comment: Ok, done, now how do I access that getData method from outside the component: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zmx3u4an/3. Show me

Comment: You would just call getData on your settings object.